# Problems with Drive API in python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, streamlit

I made an App with Python and Streamlit and I add Drive API. I have all the code as I found on the official Google page and at first it works.

I have a .csv at google drive and as I cannot save files in Heroku I save it in Drive and then download it every time I need it in the app.
At first the Dowload code works, and the .csv is dowloaded correctly but after some uploads and dowloads the download code shows this error

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Traceback:
File "D:\Users\***\drive.py", line 121, in save_response_content
    filename = re.findall("filename=\"(.+)\"", content_disposition)[0]
File "C:\Python\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
```

If I run streamlit again then it works again. But after some followed upload and dowloads it brokes again. If I check Drive, the file is correctly saved. I can't find the problem.

This is the code:

```
import os
import re
import io
import pickle
# Gmail API utils
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
          ]


def drive_authenticate():
    creds = None
    # the file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time
    if os.path.exists("token_drive.pickle"):
        with open("token_drive.pickle", "rb") as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # if there are no (valid) credentials availablle, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('token.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # save the credentials for the next run
        with open("token_drive.pickle", "wb") as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# get the Gmail API service
service = drive_authenticate()


def delete_file(filename):
    search_result = search(query=f"name='{filename}'")
    for i in range(len(search_result)):
        print('deleted: ' + search_result[i][0])
        file_id = search_result[i][0]
        file = service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()


def create_folder(folder_name):
    """
    Creates a folder and upload a file to it
    """
    # folder details we want to make
    folder_metadata = {
        "name": folder_name,
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    }
    # create the folder
    file = service.files().create(body=folder_metadata, fields="id").execute()


def upload_file (file_name, file_mimetype): #csv is text/csv
    file_metadata = {'name': file_name}
    media = MediaFileUpload(file_name, mimetype= file_mimetype)
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                        media_body=media,
                                        fields='id').execute()


def search(query): #example "mimeType='image/jpeg'" .. or .. "name='token.json'"
    result = []
    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = service.files().list(q=query,
                                              spaces='drive',
                                              fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                              pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for file in response.get('files', []):
            # Process change
            print ('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
            result.append((file.get('id'), file.get('name')))
        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break

    return result


def download(filename):
    # search for the file by name
    search_result = search(query=f"name='{filename}'")
    # get the GDrive ID of the file
    file_id = search_result[0][0]
    # make it shareable
    service.permissions().create(body={"role": "reader", "type": "anyone"}, fileId=file_id).execute()
    # download file
    download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, filename)


def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    def get_confirm_token(response):
        for key, value in response.cookies.items():
            if key.startswith('download_warning'):
                return value
        return None

    def save_response_content(response, destination):
        CHUNK_SIZE = 32768
        # get the file size from Content-length response header
        file_size = int(response.headers.get("Content-Length", 0))
        # extract Content disposition from response headers
        content_disposition = response.headers.get("content-disposition")
        # parse filename
        filename = re.findall("filename=\"(.+)\"", content_disposition)[0]
        print("[+] File size:", file_size)
        print("[+] File name:", filename)
        progress = tqdm(response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE), f"Downloading {filename}", total=file_size, unit="Byte", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024)
        with open(destination, "wb") as f:
            for chunk in progress:
                if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                    f.write(chunk)
                    # update the progress bar
                    progress.update(len(chunk))
        progress.close()

    # base URL for download
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"
    # init a HTTP session
    session = requests.Session()
    # make a request
    response = session.get(URL, params = {'id': id}, stream=True)
    print("[+] Downloading", response.url)
    # get confirmation token
    token = get_confirm_token(response)
    if token:
        params = {'id': id, 'confirm':token}
        response = session.get(URL, params=params, stream=True)
    # download to disk
    save_response_content(response, destination)
```

It seems that from time to time the downloading conection brokes and after that there is nothing you can do but wait.

When I review the whole code from pycharm everything shows the same except from this part of the code:

```
#When it works
session = requests.Session()
session
Out[]: <requests.sessions.Session at 0x1efb3332880>

response = session.get(URL, params = {'id': id}, stream=True)
response
Out[]: <Response [200]>

response.url
Out[]: 'https://doc-0c-2c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/68igeel9a4bfatoar25e8t8qm0g67tfi/1629226275000/01179996486350361096/*/1xFI06MKFhWtkZbQM8NCgur5SOlkERq-W?e=download'

response.headers
Out[]: {'X-GUploader-UploadID': '***', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'false', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Type, Date, X-Goog-Sn-Metadata, X-Goog-Sn-PatientId, GData-Version, google-cloud-resource-prefix, x-goog-request-params, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Origin, OriginToken, Pragma, Range, Slug, Transfer-Encoding, hotrod-board-name, hotrod-chrome-cpu-model, hotrod-chrome-processors, Want-Digest, x-chrome-connected, X-ClientDetails, X-Client-Version, X-Firebase-Locale, X-Goog-Firebase-Installations-Auth, X-Firebase-Client, X-Firebase-Client-Log-Type, X-Firebase-GMPID, X-Firebase-Auth-Token, X-Goog-Drive-Client-Version, X-Goog-Drive-Resource-Keys, X-GData-Client, X-GData-Key, X-GoogApps-Allowed-Domains, X-Goog-AdX-Buyer-Impersonation, X-Goog-Api-Client, X-Goog-AuthUser, ***, ***, ***, X-Goog-PageId, X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable, X-Goog-Correlation-Id, X-Goog-Request-Info, X-Goog-Request-Reason, X-Goog-Experiments, x-goog-iam-authority-selector, x-goog-iam-authorization-token, X-Goog-Spatula, X-Goog-Travel-Bgr, X-Goog-Travel-Settings, X-Goog-Upload-Command, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Disposition, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Length, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type, X-Goog-Upload-File-Name, X-Goog-Upload-Header-Content-Encoding, X-Goog-Upload-Header-Content-Length, X-Goog-Upload-Header-Content-Type, X-Goog-Upload-Header-Transfer-Encoding, X-Goog-Upload-Offset, X-Goog-Upload-Protocol, x-goog-user-project, X-Goog-Visitor-Id, X-Goog-FieldMask, X-Google-Project-Override, X-Goog-Api-Key, X-HTTP-Method-Override, X-JavaScript-User-Agent, X-Pan-Versionid, X-Proxied-User-IP, X-Origin, X-Referer, X-Requested-With, X-Stadia-Client-Context, X-Upload-Content-Length, X-Upload-Content-Type, X-Use-HTTP-Status-Code-Override, X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier, X-Android-Package, X-Ariane-Xsrf-Token, X-YouTube-VVT, X-YouTube-Page-CL, X-YouTube-Page-Timestamp, X-Compass-Routing-Destination, X-Goog-Meeting-ABR, X-Goog-Meeting-Botguardid, X-Goog-Meeting-ClientInfo, X-Goog-Meeting-ClientVersion, X-Goog-Meeting-Debugid, X-Goog-Meeting-Identifier, X-Goog-Meeting-RtcClient, X-Goog-Meeting-StartSource, X-Goog-Meeting-Token, X-Client-Data, x-sdm-id-token, X-Sfdc-Authorization, MIME-Version, Content-Transfer-Encoding, X-Earth-Engine-App-ID-Token, X-Earth-Engine-Computation-Profile, X-Earth-Engine-Computation-Profiling, X-Play-Console-Experiments-Override, X-Play-Console-Session-Id, x-alkali-account-key, x-alkali-application-key, x-alkali-auth-apps-namespace, x-alkali-auth-entities-namespace, x-alkali-auth-entity, x-alkali-client-locale, EES-S7E-MODE, cast-device-capabilities, X-Server-Timeout', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,OPTIONS', 'Content-Type': 'test/csv', 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename="df_emails.csv";filename*=UTF-8\'\'df_emails.csv', 'Date': 'Tue, 17 Aug 2021 19:27:57 GMT', 'Expires': 'Tue, 17 Aug 2021 19:27:57 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'X-Goog-Hash': 'crc32c=KcvnQQ==', 'Content-Length': '62', 'Server': 'UploadServer', 'Alt-Svc': '***"; ma=**...'}

file_size = int(response.headers.get("Content-Length", 0))
file_size
Out[]: 93

content_disposition = response.headers.get("content-disposition")
content_disposition
Out[]: 'attachment;filename="df_emails.csv";filename*=UTF-8\'\'df_emails.csv'


#When it does not work
session = requests.Session()
session
Out[]: <requests.sessions.Session at 0x16b6d381430>

response = session.get(URL, params = {'id': id}, stream=True)
response
Out[]: <Response [403]>

response.url
Out[]: 'https://doc-0c-2c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/2uvue873p1tjsu872vt03liosc91rssf/1629226875000/01179996486350361096/*/1xFI06MKFhWtkZbQM8NCgur5SOlkERq-W?e=download'

response.headers
Out[]: {'Content-Length': '1103', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Date': 'Tue, 17 Aug 2021 19:02:25 GMT', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"'}

file_size = int(response.headers.get("Content-Length", 0))
file_size
Out[]: 1103

content_disposition = response.headers.get("content-disposition")
content_disposition
#Nothing out
```

Does anyone know why does it get different responses if i does not do anything different?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a response from the service, it's always a good idea to first check the response code, **before** you try use the data you expect to have in that response.

If you have a look at the response objects, you can see that it's `<Response [200]>` when it works, and `<Response [403]>` when it doesn't.

`403` means "Forbidden". The server doesn't return to you the data you expect, that's why there is no `content-disposition` header, and your regex fails.

Comment: Thank you really much. I will do the check, anyway the response problem will not be solved, do you know any way to solve it?

Comment: Well, if it works when you connect for the first time, and then stops working after some time, it means your auth token has expired. That's absolutely normal, auth tokens usually have a limited lifetime. You need to refresh it using refresh token, or get a new one.

Comment: I found the reason:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors

An error 403 occurs when a usage limit has been exceeded or the user doesn't have the correct privileges. To determine the specific type of error, evaluate the reason field of the returned JSON

Comment: Glad to hear you've found the reason. If the answer helped you, you can accept it ;)